# Find url for webpage based on a partial file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I was introduced to a large team and not very familiar with the site I am developing for. I need to make an edit to a partial (i.e. _partial_file.html.haml) and need to verify the change visually but I don't know where that partial is being displayed on the website. Is there a way I can get a url from a partial file with rails.

For example, could I run a rake routes | grep or do something in the rails console to help find any URL where the partial is displayed?

Thanks

Comment: Why not ask one of your team mates or the person that assigned you the work?

Answer (score 2):

When you render a page you should see output in the console for all templates being rendered.

example `rendering template show.html.haml from SomeController#index`

Use this to locate the template that is including your partial. You can then use that to search the entire project for all templates including that partial.

Rails renders templates by a specific convention that maps controller methods to specific layouts and templates. I would familiarize yourself with http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html to get a better idea of how the default internals work for you rails app and use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly. While in your rails app root.

`grep -r "partial_file" .`

This will allow you to look for instances of `partial_file` and where it's being rendered.  You might see it in a view or a controller.  Depending on where you find it, you can `rake routes` and see just what url you should enter to see your output

Comment: if you're going to use grep yo can also use the grep -i 'regexcommand' this will get everything. grep is not very smart.